# Routing over a layer 2 service

Tags: cisco, routing, firewall

I have just installed a layer 2 circuit running from A location to Z location.

I have 2 firewalls with routing capabilities on both end and layer 2 functionality.

I have a server on the Z location.

Does anyone know how I can configure both devices to allow routing between the location so other subnets can access the server.

Can I configure a static route from the A location to the private IP address of the server?

Or do I need to do some sort of router on the stick configuration with VLANs?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is a bit vague in that you haven't specified what the devices you actual have are or what all their capabilities are.Please consider adding more detail to your question as a better answer might become available.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their feedback. The static routing worked, it's just the customer had some NAT issue on their firewall device that they have since resolved. Cheers for assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B: See my comment about more details.

If all devices support static routes then yes, that is one way you can achieve this.

For example, if we assign the IP subnet 192.168.0.0/30 for the new layer 2 link between Firewall A and Firewall Z, the interface on FWA facing FWZ can be assigned IP address 192.168.0.1/30 and the interface on FWZ facing FWA can be assigned IP address 192.168.0.2/30.

If FWZ has a second interface in the same subnet as the server (let’s say its 192.168.1.0/24, the FWZ interface is 192.168.1.254 and the server is 192.168.1.10); then on FWA you can configure a static route that points to 192.168.1.0/24 with the next hop address as 192.168.0.2.

If you are connecting to the server from a subnet behind FWA (let’s say FWA has an interface in a LAN range at Location A which is 192.168.2.0/24), then you will also need a static route on FWZ that points to the subnet 192.168.2.0/24 via the next hop gateway address of 192.168.0.1. This is so that return traffic from subnet can route back to that LAN behind FWA.